# shopify getting store name to build post url (python)

Tags: python, django, api, shopify

I am building a Shopify plugin .
(Placing a widget in store with SCRIPT_TAG)

with following the [standard APIs given](https://github.com/shopify/shopify_django_app)

I have achieved the auth2 setup.

now as the shop owner installs it .

[it need to call a POST method like this](http://wiki.shopify.com/Script_Tag_%28API%29#Create_a_new_script_tag)

My question is .. How can i get the STORE name and other admin information(email,etc.).. say in case if the client has store as

Storename.myshopify.com

how can i get this "storename"

to prepare a custom url calls like this :

```
POST https://api_key:shared-secret@hostname/admin/script_tags.format
```

where

```
hostname is the shop's "myshopify.com" domain (e.g. thisismyshop.myshopify.com)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've complete OAuth, you will receive a (permanent) `session token`, if you store this `session token` along with the `shop_url` you can do requests on behalf of the shop who installed your app.

Take a look at the `shopify_python_api` [documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api#saved-session), for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The API comes with access to the http://docs.shopify.com/api/shop

Note how easy it is to get the shop name.

Comment: getting shop name is easy as pie :) but I want the shop/store owners details to send him the mail once he installs my app .

Comment: Try clicking the link I sent you and reading the contents there. You'll see everything is available.

Comment: yeah .. i followed all the steps but getting this error . when tring to make a get request                                           IOError at /
('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0xb563498c>)